# Home Surveillance: How many USB camera's can one computer handle at a time and software to support it?

Tags: usb, software-rec, webcam, home-surveillance

I am looking create a home surveillance solution by using inexpensive web-cams. I would like to know how many USB-web-cams can one computer support.

Is there any software that can support multiple USB-web-cam feeds and capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have fun with USB-connected cameras unless you want lots of them within very close range of the host PC and by the time you have looked into pricey USB-extending cleverness, you might as well go for low-cost IP cameras such as the Grandtec models that are about 45 UK pounds each. Couple this to a Linux-based server running [Zoneminder](http://www.zoneminder.com/) and you're getting somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically USB-webcam capacity is defined by the server's available CPU, Ram, and any offloading it can make to a GPU.

For home surveillance I would go the minimalist route and use VLC as both the server and client software. See [VLC page](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html) for more information.